# Retrieving the data or function of the regression surface in R scatter3d package

Tags: r, function, regression, surface

Does anyone know if it is possible to view the data used for plotting the surface regression in the scatter3d package in R? What I want is to be able to somehow view the formula (or function) for the surface regression that is be applied to my data points in the scatter3d package in R.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I'm guessing you're using `scatter3d` from the `IPSUR` package.

Per the help page, 
"Value

scatter3d not return a useful value; it is used for its side-effect of creating a 3D scatterplot. indentify3d returns the labels of the identified points."

You might want to experiment with `scatterplot3D` over at CRAN to see if its returned values (functions) are of use.

You might be able to dig into the source of `scatter3d` and fork a version which returns the data.

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull answer- I will take a look at scatterplot3D and see if i can get the data in that way instead. I see that scatter3D is not written in R code but C++ so i doubt i can dig into the source code and get it to return any data.